# Retrieve an element value from an XML string during an SQL select request

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm querying a table T which has a string column `StrXML` that has XML text stored in it. Here's an example of the XML stored:

```
<Sequence mc:Ignorable="sap sads" DisplayName="Post Processing" 
          sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="424,318" 
          mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006
          xmlns:mee="clr-namespace:MatX.eRP.Entities;assembly=eRP.Entities"
          xmlns:mepa="clr-namespace:MatX.eRP.PostProcessing.Activities;assembly=PostProcessing.Activities"
          xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
          xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
          xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
          xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <mepa:BasicOperation Description="Traitement Thermique" DisplayName="HeatTreatment" Guid="82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827"     sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="402,154" Scope="Build">
        <mepa:BasicOperation.MeasurementDescriptions>
            <scg:List x:TypeArguments="mee:MeasurementDescription" Capacity="0" />
        </mepa:BasicOperation.MeasurementDescriptions>
    </mepa:BasicOperation>
    <mepa:BasicOperation Description="Finition manuelle" DisplayName="Manual Finishing" Guid="cd64be75-6968-47fe-8aac-93a4fdf37892">
        <mepa:BasicOperation.MeasurementDescriptions>
            <scg:List x:TypeArguments="mee:MeasurementDescription" Capacity="4">
                <mee:MeasurementDescription Max="{x:Null}" Min="{x:Null}" Guid="7c1a37f1-f39d-4ed3-8048-6b0a266c70b9" IsRequired="False" Name="MesureMF1" Type="Double" />
                <mee:MeasurementDescription Max="{x:Null}" Min="{x:Null}" Guid="a21b0c0d-dfff-4237-9975-4179bcefe7c2" IsRequired="False" Name="MesureMF2" Type="Double" />
            </scg:List>
        </mepa:BasicOperation.MeasurementDescriptions>
    </mepa:BasicOperation>
</Sequence>
```

In my select request on table T, I want to only show the `Description` value for which the `Guid="82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827"`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just to be more precise: I mean the "Description" for "mepa:BasicOperation"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that you can always [edit] your question. This is preferred to adding additional information in comments.

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: After one of your namespaces (`... -compatibility/2006`) you have a `"` missing. If this is real data, you are in deep troubles... (never store XML as text, if there is a native type...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment I mentioned already, that one of your namespaces is missing the final `"`. This is a big problem, if it's not just a copy-and-paste issue... (not *well formed*)

XML should not be stored in a string column (slow and dangerous!). If you database does not support XML natively the XML should at least be checked.

You did not mention the actual RDBMS, but the XQuery-principles should be the same (however your RDBMS deals with XQuery actually).

The simple approach is this `XQuery` (fetch **any** `<BasicOperation>`, wherever it is placed, and filter for the given GUID)

```
//*:BasicOperation[@Guid="82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827"]/@Description
```

With SQL-Server you can try this

```
SELECT CAST(T.StrXML AS XML).value(N'(//*:BasicOperation[@Guid="82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827"]/@Description)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
```

The more specific (and recommended) approach is this:

```
declare namespace dflt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities";
declare namespace mepa="clr-namespace:MatX.eRP.PostProcessing.Activities;assembly=PostProcessing.Activities";
dflt:Sequence/mepa:BasicOperation[@Guid="82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827"]/@Description
```

Again - with SQL-Server - you might try this:

```
SELECT CAST(T.StrXML AS XML).value(N'declare namespace dflt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities";
                                     declare namespace mepa="clr-namespace:MatX.eRP.PostProcessing.Activities;assembly=PostProcessing.Activities";
                                     (dflt:Sequence/mepa:BasicOperation[@Guid="82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827"]/@Description)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
```

If the GUID-value is variable SQL-Server would allow you to pass the value in from a variable declared outside. Read about `sql:variable()` and `sql:column()`.

### UPDATE

You can use `lower-case()` to get a secure comparison:

```
 DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
   <a guid="82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827" /> 
   <a guid="82800B59-E181-4A93-B483-7E2CD9B14827" /> 
 </root>';

 DECLARE @guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER='82800B59-E181-4A93-B483-7E2CD9B14827';

 SELECT @xml.query(N'/root/a[lower-case(@guid)=lower-case(sql:variable("@guid"))]')
```

Comment: That is working many thanks for your help. And yes I do need to pass the GUID as an SQL Server variable, what would be the change then (let's suppose the Guid source is TableB.GUID)

Comment: Just use `/mepa:BasicOperation[@Guid=sql:column("TableB.GUID")]`. If this solves your issue, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: @Rachid, From your comment I take, that this is SQL-Server. I tagged your question accordingly. SQL-Server hast got the native XML data type. You really should use this data type to store your XMLs. Much better in performance and secured against structural issues.

Comment: That's great. Last question please : how could I apply an upper-case function to the @Guid ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, **assuming** this is for **SQL Server**:

```
;WITH  XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities', 
                     'clr-namespace:MatX.eRP.PostProcessing.Activities;assembly=PostProcessing.Activities' AS mepa)
SELECT 
    T.X.value('@Description', 'varchar(100)') AS JobTitle
FROM 
    @XTable
CROSS APPLY
    XmlData.nodes('/Sequence/mepa:BasicOperation') AS T(X)
WHERE
    T.X.value('@Guid','varchar(50)') = '82800b59-e181-4a93-b483-7e2cd9b14827'
```

Comment: I'd always try to do the filtering within `XQuery`. With big sets your appraoch has to read the full resultset, just to throw most of it away.